# FieldFile object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, django

I'm testing out a few options. I have uploaded a file using django-storages with S3 and it works fine. However, when I try and read the file with the code below I get the following error:

> 'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'

**Why?**

Even default_storage.exists(self.filepath) give the same error.

```
 csv_file = default_storage.open(self.filepath, 'r')


 new_object = CSVImport(csvfile=csv_file.read(),
                        model=Contact,
                        modelspy=".",
                        mappings="1=first_name,2=mobile,3=email,4=last_name,5=43,6=16")

 new_object.run()
```

**Full Error:**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contacts/upload/configurator/95/

Django Version: 1.5.1
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'south',
 'userena',
 'social_auth',
 'djcelery',
 'storages',
 'endless_pagination',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'django_sagepay',
 'guardian',
 'widget_tweaks',
 'badger',
 'tastypie',
 'accounts',
 'contacts',
 'sms',
 'smartpages',
 'django_sagepay',
 'unsubscribe',
 'core',
 'django_nose',
 'debug_toolbar')
Installed Middleware:
('dogslow.WatchdogMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'async_messages.middleware.AsyncMiddleware',
 'core.middleware.ssl.SSLRedirect',
 'core.middleware.account.RefreshBalance',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/t/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/t/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/t/contacts/views.py" in upload_configurator
  201.             process_upload_Temp(upload_id=upload.id, cleaned_data=data)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/t/contacts/views.py" in process_upload_Temp
  222.     upload.process(cleaned_data=cleaned_data)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/t/contacts/models.py" in process
  169.         csv_file = default_storage.open(self.filepath, 'r')
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/t/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in open
  36.         return self._open(name, mode)
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/t/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py" in _open
  237.         name = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(name))
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/t/django-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/storages/backends/s3boto.py" in _clean_name
  204.         return os.path.normpath(name).replace('\\', '/')
File "/Users/user/Documents/workspace/t/django-env/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py" in normpath
  318.     initial_slashes = path.startswith('/')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /contacts/upload/configurator/95/
Exception Value: 'FieldFile' object has no attribute 'startswith'


I have tried:

csv_file.read() gives same error.

Full Error details:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error is thrown by:

```
csv_file = default_storage.open(self.filepath, 'r')
```

which tells that the type of `self.filepath` is `FieldFile`. So given its name, I'd expect that object to be an already opened file. So you should try:

```
new_object = CSVImport(csvfile=self.filepath.read(), ... )
```

But I may be wrong, and `self.filepath` could be a file containing the path to the file you want to open... It's hard to tell given your code sample, I can only guess.

Comment: I have tried csvfile=self.filepath.read() but I get a long error with all the CSV contents in: 'Could not open specified csv file, 1111yn,0827654543,test@test.com,1\ned,123,1111,111\name, etc etc etc

Comment: and csvfile=self.filepath on its own gives error: oercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, FieldFile found

Comment: did you try `csvfile=self.filepath.read()` and not `csvfile=self.filepath`?

Comment: Yep, I tried self.filepath.read() but this again gives the weird error: 'Could not open specified csv file and then splits out the entire CSV contents in the error!

Comment: then you solved your first problem, by having a new one! that's good news ! :-)

Comment: now it looks like your CSV file is not easily parseable. You may want to ask another question, with a sample content of your CSV file, and the `new_object = CSVImport()` line, as well as the stacktrace you're getting. So you keep it the Stackoverflow way: one question, one answer. Another question? Make a new post! Always remember that you're making questions to get help solving your problems, but also to help others having similar problems solving theirs.

Answer (score 0):

Your are passing a `FieldFile` object to `default_storage.open()` but it expects the file name as a string. Give it the name that was used to save the file instead of a `FieldFile` object.

Comment: how do I get the name from self.filepath? I have tried self.filepath.name also but gives weird error:'Could not open specified csv file and then splits out the entire file contents in the error!